# SSL/TLS dynamic key generation

Tags: java, android, ssl, tls1.2

On this project of mine I needed to implement secure connection using SSL/TLS between a client and a server. I found a good article about that so I've managed to do my task without any problem.

[This is the article](http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2011/11/24/creating-self-signed-certificates-for-use-on-android/).

My question is pretty simple but I cannot find an answer anywhere. In this particular case, my clients have the same key in the SSL protocol which is created through tutorial on a previous link and put in some kind of a file. Potential problem in this process is that someone can access that file and since every client has that key, someone can listen to all connections.

What I wanted to ask, is there any chance to dynamically generate keys every time some client wants to access the server and put the generated key in the server truststore?

**UPDATE**

```
public static final String PATH_TO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE = "and/client.bks";
public static final String PATH_TO_ANDROID_TRUSTSTORE = "and/clienttruststore.bks";

String pathToKeyStore = PATH_TO_ANDROID_KEYSTORE;
String pathToTrustStore = PATH_TO_ANDROID_TRUSTSTORE;

KeyStore keyStoreKeys = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStoreKeys.load(Gdx.files.internal(pathToKeyStore).read(), passphrase);

KeyStore keyStoreTrust = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
keyStoreTrust.load(Gdx.files.internal(pathToTrustStore).read(), passphrase);

KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
keyManagerFactory.init(keyStoreKeys, passphrase);

TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
trustManagerFactory.init(keyStoreTrust);
```

This is the client code and seems like clients have exported server's certificates in their truststores but they actually use the same private key that is generated only once in the keystore using openssl tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In this particular case, my clients have the same key in the SSL protocol which is created through tutorial on a previous link and put in some kind of a file.

Unclear. Do you mean they share the same *private* key? If so, that is a flaw in your system design. Every client should have its own private key. Otherwise the private key isn't, err, private. And access to that key should be via a keystore whose password only the applicion knows, which provides at least another line of defence.

If you just mean that they all have an exported copy of the server's *certificate*, in their *truststores*, there is no security risk attached to that at all: it is perfectly normal.

> Potential problem in this process is that someone can access that file and since every client has that key, someone can listen to all connections.

No they can't. SSL is immune to man-in-the-middle attacks provided you don't compromise your *server's* private key, but if you're talking about client private keys they can masquerade as a real client even if they aren't, *if* they can break through the keystore-password barrier.

> What I wanted to ask, is there any chance to dynamically generate keys every time some client wants to access the server and put the generated key in the server truststore?

Not securely, and not online. If your genuine clients can do it, so can an attacker. That's why trust material must be distributed offline.

Comment: I think that they might share the same private key since I generated it only once using openssl tool but I also think they have an exported server's certificate in their truststores since that was the goal in the given article. I put an update with the provided client code so it might be a little clearer.

If the case is that my clients share only one private key, how can I achieve they have their own private key during the communication?

Btw, I really appreciate your breathless explanation!

Comment: You have to either distribute a different private key with each copy of the client, or else have it generate its own private key on installation, and, somehow, securely, register that with the server on first use.

Comment: Can you think of some code example that I might want to take a look at?

Comment: It's not a coding problem. It's a key distribution problem.